How to dynamically push the overflowing elements into a dropdown
Problem Statement
I have a simple dynamic navigation bar (the number of items and the text can be changed). I want to show the first X items on the screen that can fit in one line along with a "Show more" dropdown where all the overflowing items will go i.e., items left after fitting the first X items in a line.
Possible Solution
I tried achieving this by calculating the width of each item (text width + button padding), checking the width of the screen, and then putting only the first X items whose combined width (plus the width of the "show more" button) is less than screen width. Now the challenging part is to calculate the text width. If we first render all the elements, then it is easy to get the rendered width of each item, and then we can do the above calculation to check what elements fit in a single line. However, this approach would initially render all the elements and is not a performance-optimized solution.

Don't just describe your solution attempt; include all the relevant code so we can recreate the problem and suggestion solutions.

@mykaf It is basically the answer given by jla

To compute the width of each item, it must be rendered by the browser. Finding a solution where it is not first rendered sounds suspiciously like premature optimisation. Unless you have thousands of top-level items in your menu, the time spent rendering them is negligible; particularly when compared against the time it would take an alternative scripting solution to run.
As the following code show, the JavaScript logic is quite simple, and shouldn't have any noticeable effect on performance. The entire list of top-level items only needs to be iterated over once.


window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const menu = document.querySelector( '#menu' )
    const items = menu.querySelectorAll( '.item' )
    const viewMore = menu.querySelector( '.view-more' )
    const overflow = menu.querySelector( '#overflow-menu' )
    
    const maxWidth = menu.offsetWidth
    let accumulator = viewMore.offsetWidth
    let c = 0
    
    while ( accumulator <= maxWidth && c < items.length - 1 ) {
        accumulator += items[c].offsetWidth
        c++
    }
    
    for ( c--; c < items.length; c++ ) {
        if ( ! items[c].classList.contains( 'view-more' ) ) {
            overflow.appendChild(items[c]);
        }
    }
    
    viewMore.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
        overflow.classList.toggle( 'visible' ) 
    } )
} )
#menu {
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: black;
}
.item.view-more {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
#overflow-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
}
#overflow-menu.visible {
    display: flex;
}
<div id="menu">
  <div class="item">Text</div>
  <div class="item">Of Varying</div>
  <div class="item">Lengths</div>
  <div class="item">That The Browser</div>
  <div class="item">Must</div>
  <div class="item">Render</div>
  <div class="item">In</div>
  <div class="item">Order To</div>
  <div class="item">Determine</div>
  <div class="item">The</div>
  <div class="item">Final Width</div>
  <div class="item">:)</div>
  
  <div class="item view-more">
      View More
      <div id="overflow-menu"></div>
  </div>
</div>



